# How would I go about "adding" the contents of different SQL Tables together?

Tags: sql

Sorry if this is a weird question or if it's already been answered on stack before... I just can't think of a way of explaining what it is I'm actually trying to do.

Basically, imagine that you have two SQL tables, containing two different recipes.

Table 1 has:

- 2 potatoes
- 1 carrot
- 200 grams of flour

Table 2 has:

- 1 potato
- 3 celery sticks
- 100 grams of flour

So the result of these two tables being added together would be:

- 3 potatoes
- 1 carrot
- 3 celery sticks
- 300 grams of flour

How would you add these tables together? Is storing this data in different SQL tables a good idea, or a bad one?  Happy for other/better ways to store the data.

Any help would be appreciated :)

(first post on SO, sorry if its an awful question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing those things in 2 tables is a bad idea. A better DB design would be

```
ingredients table
-----------------
id
name
...


recipes table
--------------
id
name
description
...


units table
-----------
id
name


recipes_ingredients table
--------------------------
recipe_id
ingredient_id
amount_value
amount_unit_id
```

Then to get all ingredients of a specific recipe you can do

```
select i.name, ri.amount_value, u.name
from recipes r
join recipes_ingredients ri on ri.recipe_id = r.id
join units u on ri.amount_unit_id = u.id
join ingredients i on ri.ingredient_id = i.id
where r.name = 'Pizza'
```

If you want to get only distinct ingredients then you can group by

```
select i.name as ingredient, 
       sum(ri.amount_value) as total_amount, 
       u.name as unit
from recipes r
join recipes_ingredients ri on ri.recipe_id = r.id
join units u on ri.amount_unit_id = u.id
join ingredients i on ri.ingredient_id = i.id
where r.name = 'Pizza'
group by i.name, u.name
```

Comment: Thanks man :)  So, in that case, when retrieving the total values of all the ingredients, what would the SELECT query look like?

Comment: So, I ran the query and this is the result

 Potato             2 Grams   
---
 Carrot             1 Each    
---
 Rump Steak 1 Grams    
---
 Carrot         2  Each  
---
There are duplicate "carrot" returns... how would I make all these ingredients add up together?

Comment: Brilliant work. This might be pushing the friendship (it probably is...) but what would this kind of query look like in LINQ-SQL? (I can wrap my head around LINQ for the basic stuff, but it would be awesome to see something like the above in LINQ so I could understand the differences between the two languages)

Comment: Sorry, I am not a LINQ expert.